# How to manually install Ubuntu Server

Tags: web-server, server

I'm interested in buying Raspberry Pi 4. I'd like to create simple server for testing my applications and storing data (home cloud). I wonder if I can manually install Ubuntu Server like on standard computer. Can I boot from USB and install OS on SD card / external disk instead of burning preinstalled Raspbian / Ubuntu?

Comment: USB booting is not generally available on an RPi4, it's still in early beta testing. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=196778 is the best way to boot a RPi4 from a USB device right now.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to visit the [download site](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) and 
select your version.  I would go for the 64bit 20.04 for your proposed Pi 4B and drop it onto an SD card for now.

Play around for a few weeks till the USB SSD/HDD boot is a bit more complete or help out and test the [beta software](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=274595).

I have one 20.04 Intel box running with around 8Tb of data so far as a temporary NAS and not broken it yet :)

Comment: Thanks. But is there an option install Ubuntu manually (preferably expert mode) going this way? I don't really need to boot from USB if only I can install "custom" version.